# Flask - How to Get URL of the page that led to a form?

Tags: python, html, flask

If 2 different URLs lead to the same form, how do you determine with URL requested the form?

On the URLs `"/page1"` and `"/page2"`, there is an "Add" button that leads to the same form with the same URL, `"/form1"`.

If `"/page1"` led to the form page, then I'd like to redirect to `"/page1"` after the form is submitted, and similarly for `"/page2"`.

This is the code I tried:

```
@app.route("/page1", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def page1():

    # Do something

    return render_template("page1.html", title = "Page 1")


@app.route("/page2", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def page1():

    # Do something

    return render_template("page2.html", title = "Page 1")


@app.route("/form1", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def form1():

    form = SomeForm()
    # Do something

   if form.validate_on_submit():
       if request.url == "http://127.0.0.1:5000/page1":
           return(redirect(url_for('page1'))

       elif request.url == "http://127.0.0.1:5000/page2":
           return(redirect(url_for('page2'))    

    return render_template("form1.html", title = "Page 1", form = form)
```

But it seems I misunderstood what `request.url` does, as it returns the URL the form is on.

So, what method should I use to determine whether it was page1 or page2 that led to the form? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution. Looks like you need to use `request.referrer`.

```
@app.route("/form1", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def form1():

    form = SomeForm()
    # Do something

    # Use request.referrer before validation.
    prev_url = request.referrer

   if form.validate_on_submit():
       if request.url == "http://127.0.0.1:5000/page1":
           return(redirect(url_for('page1'))

   elif request.url == "http://127.0.0.1:5000/page2":
       return(redirect(url_for('page2'))    

return render_template("form1.html", title = "Page 1", form = form)
```